# Kubernetes simple authentication

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, coreos

I am using Kubernetes on a coreOS cluster hosted on DigitalOcean.
And using [this](https://github.com/cescoferraro/kubernetes-do) repo to set it up. I started the apiserver with the following line:

```
    /opt/bin/kube-apiserver --runtime-config=api/v1 --allow-privileged=true \ 
     --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --insecure-port=8080 \
     --secure-port=6443 --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
     --logtostderr=true --advertise-address=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \
     --service-cluster-ip-range=10.100.0.0/16 --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

The problem is that it accepts requests from anyone! I want to be able to provide a simple user/password authentication. I have been reading [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/authentication.md) and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/security.md) and it seems that I have to do something like the below, but I cannot afford to take the cluster down for a long period of time, so I need your guys to help with this one. Btw, my pods do not create another pods, so I only need a few user, like 1/2 for devs and 1 for CI.

I am thinking of doing something like including authorization-mode and authorization-policy-file flags as it seems required and making the insecure-bind-address localhost to make it only available locally. I am missing something?

```
    /opt/bin/kube-apiserver --runtime-config=api/v1 --allow-privileged=true \ 
     --authorization-mode=ABAC --authorization-policy-file=/access.json \
     --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --insecure-port=8080 \
     --secure-port=6443 --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
     --logtostderr=true --advertise-address=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4} \
     --service-cluster-ip-range=10.100.0.0/16 --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

###/access.json

```
{"user":"admin"}
{"user":"wercker"}
{"user":"dev1"}
{"user":"dev2"}
```

But where are the passwords? How do I actually make the request with kubectl and curl or httpie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want your users to authenticate using HTTP Basic Auth (user:password), you can add:

```
--basic-auth-file=/basic_auth.csv
```

to your kube-apiserver command line, where each line of the file should be `password, user-name, user-id`. E.g.:

```
@dm1nP@ss,admin,admin
w3rck3rP@ss,wercker,wercker
etc...
```

If you'd rather use access tokens (HTTP Authentication: Bearer), you can specify:

```
--token-auth-file=/known-tokens.csv
```

where each line should be `token,user-name,user-id[,optional groups]`. E.g.:

```
@dm1nT0k3n,admin,admin,adminGroup,devGroup
w3rck3rT0k3n,wercker,wercker,devGroup
etc...
```

For more info, checkout the [Authentication docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/). Also checkout [example_policy_file.jsonl](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/auth/authorizer/abac/example_policy_file.jsonl) for an example ABAC file.

Comment: I got it working man! Thanks. Last question;I got i working with 
something like `kubectl -s="https://SERVER:6443" --username="admin" --password="PASSWORD" get pods -o wide` but I was expecting to have access the api with `curl --header "Authorization: (admin:PASSWORD)" --insecure http://SERVER:6443/api`  with the (admin:PASSWORD) string encoded on base64 UTF-8

Comment: Glad it works! You'll probably also need "Basic" in the Authorization Header: --header "Authorization: Basic base64(admin:PASSWORD)".

Comment: curl does it better curl -u admin:PASSWORD -i -H 'Accept:application/json' --insecure  https:// SERVER:6443/api Can you take a look at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951253/can-kubectl-remember-me

Comment: CJ Cullen. You may consider adding this piece of the doc to your answer. 
"tokens are just long alphanumeric strings, e.g. 32 chars. See
TOKEN=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64 | tr -d "=+/" | dd bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null)

Comment: Even a more basic question. Add "--basic-auth-file=/basic_auth.csv" to what command. nube question.

Comment: __basic auth is deprecated in > 1.19__ [according to the release notes](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/)