# can Kubectl remember me?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, coreos

I have implemented basic authentication on my kubernetes api-server, now I am trying to configure my `./kube/config` file in a way I could simply run, `kubectl get pods`

```
 kubectl config set-cluster digitalocean \
                      --server=https://SERVER:6443 \
                      --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true \
                      --api-version="v1" 
 kubectl config set-context digitalocean --cluster=digitalocean --user=admin
 kubectl config set-credentials admin --password="PASSWORD" 
 kubectl config use-context digitalocean
```

But now, it asks for credentials twice like :

```
dev@desktop: ~/code/go/src/bitbucket.org/cescoferraro                                                                   
$ kubectl get pods                                                                                                      
Please enter Username: admin                                                                                             
enter Password: PASSWORD
Please enter Username: admin                                                                                            
Please enter Password: PASSWORD                                                                                      
NAME                                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
```

or I need to pass the flags like

```
kubectl get pods --username=admin --password=PASSWORD
```

is this the default behavior? I want my config to know me. What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you provide the output of `kubectl config view`? I think the problem might be you need to do something like

`kubectl config set-credentials cluster-admin --username=admin --password=PASSWORD`

instead of

`kubectl config set-credentials admin --password="PASSWORD"`.