# How to configure Basic Authentication Configuration in Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

How to configure Basic Authentication Configuration In kubernetes Dashbaord .I have done below steps

1. **--authentication-mode=basic** added in kubernetes dashboard deployment yaml.
2. Done API server  to be configured (inside /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml" with authorization mode **ABAC** and **--basic-auth-file** given to a file and that file contain like "**userpass,username,uid**"

But still unable to get the result . Whatever I wrote (even random letter) in the username and password field it able to login into the dashboard and no resources access after that.

Answer (score 1):

one way to achieve is by fronting the dashboard service with a traefik ingress controller. set basic auth in traefik deployment file. create ingress rule for dashboard service

you can also use nginx ingress controller.
below link would be helpful

https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/auth

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942193/kubernetes-simple-authentication). Did you resolve this issue?